CORS policy issues on integrating Xero's API into Nuxt 3
I'm trying to integrate Xero's OAuth 2 into my Nuxt 3 App and I kept getting issues with CORS policy.
Nuxt App > pages > index.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import UiParentCard from "@/components/shared/UiParentCard.vue";

const handleXeroConnection = async () => {
  await $fetch("/api/xero/connect");
};
</script>

<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="12">
      <UiParentCard title="Xero">
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="handleXeroConnection">Connect</v-btn>
      </UiParentCard>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

Nuxt App > server > api > xero > Connect.ts
import { XeroClient } from "xero-node";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const xero = new XeroClient({
    clientId: process.env.XERO_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.XERO_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    redirectUris: ["https://example.com"],
    scopes: "openid profile email accounting.transactions offline_access".split(
      " ",
    ),
  });

  const consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
  return await sendRedirect(event, consentUrl, 302);
});

Xero App Details

Xero App Configuration

Expectation
I expect to get redirected to Xero's user content page by clicking the "Connect" button. Instead, I got a CORS issue even though I've configured the Xero App already. I'm unsure of how to resolve this issue
Errors
connect:1  Access to fetch at 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=...&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20accounting.transactions%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com' (redirected from 'https://example.com/api/xero/connect') from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
        
GET https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=...&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20accounting.transactions%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com net::ERR_FAILED 302 (Found)

FetchError: [GET] "/api/xero/connect": <no response> Failed to fetch
    at async u (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:21797)
    at async v (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:22488)
    at async t (2Dp-ibzY.js:1:300)Caused by: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at u (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:21688)
    at d (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:20450)
    at u (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:21803)
    at async v (CBHDmVuJ.js:18:22488)
    at async t (2Dp-ibzY.js:1:300)


OAuth providers do not allow to fetch the login URL in the background - for the very obvious reason, that users need to be able to verify via their browser address bar, that they are not entering their credentials into a phishing form. /api/xero/connect redirects to that login URL - which means, that you can not fetch /api/xero/connect in the background to begin with; you need to directly send the user there.
